# The Spawned enemy only moves, but not shoots in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity. Recently, I have started making a survival fps game, there, I have 1 enemy, when I kill him, it will spawn more enemies. However, the spawned only move, but not shoot. Although, I have attached a script to it. here are all my code.

prefab_shooting-

```
  using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class prefab_shooting : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float damage = 1f;
        public float range = 100f;
    
        public GameObject player;
        public GameObject enemy;
    
        private void Start()
        {
            player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
            enemy = GameObject.FindWithTag("PBR");
        }
    
        private void Update()
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.transform.position) < 25.0f)
            {
                Debug.Log(damage);
            }
        }
    
        void Shoot()
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
    
            if (Physics.Raycast(enemy.transform.position, enemy.transform.forward, out hit, range))
            {
                if (hit.transform.tag == "Player")
                {
                    swat_death swat = hit.transform.GetComponent<swat_death>();
                   // Debug.Log(damage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

PBR_shooting (the enemy shooting)-

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PBR_shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 1f;
    public float range = 100f;

    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject enemy;

    private void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
        enemy = GameObject.FindWithTag("PBR");
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.transform.position) < 25.0f)
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(enemy.transform.position, enemy.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            if(hit.transform.tag == "Player")
            {
                swat_death swat = hit.transform.GetComponent<swat_death>();
              //  Debug.Log(swat.health);
                swat.TakeDamage(damage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Swat_death (player_death) -

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class swat_death : MonoBehaviour
{
    static float health = 250f;
    public GameObject player;
 
    public void TakeDamage(float amount)
    {
        health -= amount;

        Debug.Log(health);

        if (health <= 0f)
        {
            Debug.Log("STOP");
            SceneManager.LoadScene("death_scene");
        }
    }

    void Die()
    {

    } 

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.transform.tag == "enemy_bullet")
        {
            //SceneManager.LoadScene("death_scene");
        }
    }


}
```

And the PBR_Death (from where the spawning starts) -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PBR_death : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    Animator anim;

    public int XPos;
    public int ZPos;

    public GameObject TheEnemy;
    public int enemyCount = 0;

    public int points = 1;
    public GameObject enemyGameObject;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        enemyGameObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("PBR");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.transform.tag == "bullet")
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("isDying");
            enemy_movement enemy = GetComponent<enemy_movement>();
            enemy.enabled = false;
            PBR_shooting shoot = GetComponent<PBR_shooting>();
            shoot.enabled = false;
            scoreManager.score += points;

            GameObject go = Instantiate(enemyGameObject, new Vector3(Random.Range(34, 0), Random.Range(34, 0), 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            go.AddComponent<prefab_movement>();
            go.AddComponent<prefab_death>();
            go.AddComponent<prefab_shooting>();

            // StartCoroutine(EnemySpawner());
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Pls help me, I am stuck in this for almost 3 days..

Comment: Not sure how your scripts belong together exactly but in `prefab_shooting` you never call `Shoot` .. you only log something ..  you also don't call `swat.TakeDamage(damage)` ...  the rest of the code looks just the same so why have a different component that does basically exactly the same?

Comment: Oh Gosh!!!, I am really so so sorry, that I forgot to call the function. It was such a silly question... Thank you so much @derHugo.. :) :D

Comment: Also just in general: Do you really want to shoot **every frame** once you are in range? I guess you should rather add some cooldown time ;)

Comment: well, can u explain me a bit briefly...

Comment: well, can I ask another question ???, although it is spawning and shooting, it doesn't stops.. how can I limit it ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### You didn't call the function

In your first script **(prefab_shooting-)** You didn't call the `Shoot()` function.

Comment: well, ya done... thank you so much.. for helping.. :D Such a silly mistake....

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I already said? ... [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions) ;)

Comment: well, thnx to both, from now on I will pay more attention, and try not to make such silly mistakes anymore.. thank you :) :D

Comment: well, can I ask another question ???, although it is spawning and shooting, it doesn't stops.. how can I limit it ??

Comment: I could explain the whole way if you make it a new question :> (For the formatting and the reputation)